# How to add background image on a material ui Dialog component

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image, material-ui

I'm using `material-ui version 3.9.3` in my React application. I want to add a background image on a dialog. I'm using the `Dialog` component for it but I'm unable to add a background image on the whole dialog.
For example:

```
    <Dialog
       fullScreen={fullScreen}
        open={this.props.open}
        onClose={this.handleClose}
        aria-labelledby='responsive-dialog-title'
        >
        <DialogTitle
          id='customized-dialog-title'
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          noCloseButtonNeeded={noCloseButtonNeeded}
        >
          {/* some jsx */}
         </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          {children}
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
```

I have tried to add an image using classes and custom CSS but I'm unable to do it. 
Can anyone help me out to add it? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can define the background image in a `styles` object that can be used with the [withStyles](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component) higher-order component to apply it to the dialog:

```
const styles = {
  dialog: {
    backgroundImage: "url(https://i.imgur.com/HeGEEbu.jpg)"
  }
};
```

When you pass this object to the `withStyles` HOC, it will supply your component with a `classes` prop containing properties with the same names as the properties on `styles` that you've defined.

Next, you can apply this class to the `Dialog` by taking advantage of the [classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes) prop (the specific overrides made available for the `Dialog` component are detailed [here](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/#css)):

```
<Dialog ... classes={{paper: classes.dialog}}>
        {/* ... */}
</Dialog>
```

This is telling material-ui to merge the styles you have defined in `styles.dialog` with the default styles on the `Paper` element that is used with the Dialog.

You'll need to make sure that you're wrapping your component in the `withStyles` HoC.  If you have a class component, it will look something like this:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(DialogWithBackgroundImage);
```

For functional components, it would look something like:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(({open, children, classes}) => (<Dialog ...></Dialog>))
```

Here's a working example that ties everything together: https://codesandbox.io/embed/q3zy4r2np4